# Best way to use Xcode with 2 Firebase projects - 2 GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I have a Xcode project which builds an app which is used in two parts of the world. We currently have a Firebase Project for each project which translates to two GoogleService-Info.plist for each file. What is the best way to manage this inside Xcode project? The way I was thinking of was having 2 targets named appropriately and have the files be in the Target membership for the appropriate target.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create another target. You can just create another Scheme for the same target. `Product > Scheme > New Scheme`

With your new scheme created you can go into the `Build Settings > Info.plist File` and set each configuration to their respective GoogleService-Info.plist.

Comment: How does that work? In the new scheme there is no way to change the GoogleService-Info.plist.

The GoogleService-Info.plist is not specified anywhere, it is picked up like the info.plist

Comment: You can double click on the property in build settings and change the path to your google info.plist